# How are pointers interpreted differently to variables in a control flow graph (CFG)?

Tags: formal-methods, software-verification, c++

I have been working with control flow graphs and believe I understand how they function when describing dependencies between variables. For example, given the operations:

```
a = b + c;
b = c + d;
c = d + e;
```

The control flow graph would appear:

```
a = b + c; ==> b = c + d; ==> c = d + e;
```

Since there is a write after read dependency involving b and c in the second and third operations respectively.

How would this change if instead of variables pointers were represented in the graph?

```
*a = *b + *c;
*b = *c + *d;
*c = *d + *e;
```

Comment: Is this to do with compiler optimization?

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER SCIENCE @SE. Can `a` and `c` refer to the same location? `b`&`d`?

Comment: Yes, this is an exercise to explore compiler optimizations and multi threading. I believe a and c, b and c could refer to the same address in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! Typically, pointer dereferences are treated no differently than any other operation, like addition and multiplication. So the control flow graph would be:

```
*a = *b + *c; ==> *b = *c + *d; ==> *c = *d + *e;
```

Sometimes, when building a CFG it is useful to break up a complex expression into its individual steps. In that case, we would get something like this:

```
b' = *b
==> c' = *c
==> a' = b' + c'
==> *a = a'
==> c' = *c
==> d' = *d
==> b' = c' + d'
==> *b = b'
==> d' = *d
==> e' = *e
==> *c = c'
```

As an interesting side note, it may seem like this last CFG can be simplified: we have `c' = *c` twice, and `*c` does not change in the meantime, so we should remove the second `c' = *c` line, right? Actually no, because it is possible that the operation `*a = a'` modifies `*c`, in the case that `a` and `c` are pointers to the same location in memory.